# I am not able to find a fragment added dynamically, fragment manager is always returning null

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment dynamically in a container in main activity. I wish to use the fragment instance at a later stage but fragment manager is always returning null. What am i doing wrong?

I have tried this multiple times. The fragments are being added as can be seen by running the app but i am not able to find them.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Starting OnCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.list_frag_cont, new ListFrag(),"listfrag").commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.detail_frag_cont, new DetailFrag(),"detailfrag").commit();
        ListFrag listFrag=(ListFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("listfrag");
        DetailFrag detailFrag=(DetailFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("detailfrag");
        if(listFrag==null)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: listFrag is null");
        if(detailFrag==null)
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: detailFrag is null");
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Exitting OnCreate");
```

The expected log should be

```
2019-07-07 16:59:57.098 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: Starting OnCreate
2019-07-07 16:59:57.224 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: Exitting OnCreate
```

but here is the log i am getting

```
2019-07-07 16:59:57.098 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: Starting OnCreate
2019-07-07 16:59:57.224 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: listFrag is null
2019-07-07 16:59:57.224 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: detailFrag is null
2019-07-07 16:59:57.224 10087-10087/com.kinshuu.silverbook D/MyLOGS: onCreate: Exitting OnCreate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the answer, that is because the transactions are not committed immediately. For that you need to use fragmentmanager. executependingchanges.